# OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000002369EF14000

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have the same error as many of the questions here: OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000002369EF14000. However, the situation is different and I couldn't figure out why this happens. Moreover, the address appears to be different every time I run the code.

I ran the following python code and get the error above. How do I fix this issue? (Or what is the general cause for the OSError: exception: access violation reading error?)

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

splines = CDLL('splines.dll')
splines.spline_basis.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_int),
                                 POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_int)]
x = np.random.rand(10)
ord = 3
knots = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
nk = len(knots)
nx = len(x)
ind = sorted(range(x.shape[0]), key=lambda k: x[k])
sortx = x[ind]
derivs = nx
derivs = [derivs if i == 0 else np.nan for i in ind]
ncoef = nk - ord
temp = splines.spline_basis(np.array(knots).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), POINTER(c_int)(c_int(ncoef)),
                            POINTER(c_int)(c_int(ord)),
                            sortx.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), np.array(derivs).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int)),
                            POINTER(c_int)(c_int(nx)), np.zeros([ord, nx]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)),
                            POINTER(c_int)(c_int(nx)))
print(temp)
```

The dll file is compiled from the c code below, which builds a spline basis. The main function used is the `spline_basis` function

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "splines.h"

double* ldel, * rdel;
long orderm1;

void
    diff_table(double* ti, double x, int ndiff)
{
    register double* r = rdel, * l = ldel, * dpt = ti;

    while (ndiff--) {
        *r++ = *dpt++ - x;
        *l++ = x - *--ti;
    }
}

void
    basis_funcs(double* ti, double x, double* b)
{
    int j, r;
    double saved, term;

    diff_table(ti, x, orderm1);
    b[0] = 1.;
    for (j = 1; j <= orderm1; j++) {
        saved = 0.;
        for (r = 0; r < j; r++) {
            term = b[r] / (rdel[r] + ldel[j - 1 - r]);
            b[r] = saved + rdel[r] * term;
            saved = ldel[j - 1 - r] * term;
        }
        b[j] = saved;
    }
}

double
    evaluate(double* ti, double x, double* a, int nder)
{
    register double* lpt, * rpt, * apt;
    register int inner;
    int outer = orderm1;

    while (nder--) {
        for (inner = outer, apt = a, lpt = ti - outer; inner--; apt++, lpt++)
            *apt = outer * (*(apt + 1) - *apt) / (*(lpt + outer) - *lpt);
        outer--;
    }
    diff_table(ti, x, (long)outer);
    while (outer--)
        for (apt = a, lpt = ldel + outer, rpt = rdel, inner = outer + 1;
            inner--; lpt--, rpt++, apt++)
            *apt = (*(apt + 1) * *lpt + *apt * *rpt) / (*rpt + *lpt);
    return(*a);
}

void
    spline_value(double* knots, double* coeff, int * ncoeff,
        int * order, double* x, int * nx, int * deriv,
        double* y)
{
    long n = *nx;
    double* a, * last = knots + *ncoeff;
    a = calloc(*order, sizeof(double));
    orderm1 = *order - 1L;  /* allocate difference tables */
    rdel = calloc(orderm1, sizeof(double));
    ldel = calloc(orderm1, sizeof(double));

    knots += *order;        /* First *order knots must be <= all x's */
    while (n--) {
        while (knots <= last && *knots <= *x) { knots++; coeff++; }
        memcpy(a, coeff, *order);
        *y++ = evaluate(knots, *x++, a, (int)*deriv);
    }
    free(ldel); free(rdel); free(a);
}

void spline_basis(double* knots, int * ncoeff, int * order,
    double* xvals, int * derivs, int * nx,
    double* basis, int * offsets)
{               /* evaluate the non-zero B-spline basis */
                /* functions (or their derivatives) at */
                /* xvals.  */
    int n = *nx, i, j;
    double* dpt, * coeff, * last = knots + *ncoeff;

    orderm1 = *order - 1L;
    rdel = calloc(orderm1, sizeof(double));
    ldel = calloc(orderm1, sizeof(double));
    coeff = calloc(*order, sizeof(double));
    dpt = (knots += *order);    /* first *order knots must be <= all xvals */
    for (; n--; xvals++, derivs++) {
        while (dpt < last && *dpt <= *xvals) dpt++;
        if (*derivs) {      /* slow method for derivatives */
            for (i = 0; i < *order; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < *order; j++) coeff[j] = 0;
                coeff[i] = 1;
                *basis++ = evaluate(dpt, *xvals, coeff, (int)*derivs);
            }
        }
        else {
            basis_funcs(dpt, *xvals, basis); /* fast method for value */
            basis += *order;
        }
        *offsets++ = (long)(dpt - knots);
    }
    free(ldel); free(rdel); free(coeff);
}

void lin_interp(double* x, double* y, double* x0, double* y0, int * nvals)
{
    int n = *nvals;
    double* firstx = x;

    while (n--) {
        while (*x < *x0) { x++; y++; }
        if (x > firstx) { x--; y--; }
        if (*x > * x0) *y0++ = *y + (*(y + 1) - *y) * (*x0 - *x) / (*(x + 1) - *x);
        else *y0++ = *y;
        x0++;
    }
}
```

The header file includes declaration of functions only.

```
void diff_table(double* ti, double x, int ndiff);
void basis_funcs(double* ti, double x, double* b);
double evaluate(double* ti, double x, double* a, int nder);
void spline_value(double* knots, double* coeff, int* ncoeff, int* order, double* x, int* nx, int* deriv, double* y);
__declspec(dllexport) void spline_basis(double* knots, int* ncoeff, int* order, double* xvals, int* derivs, int* nx, double* basis, int* offsets);
void lin_interp(double* x, double* y, double* x0, double* y0, int* nvals);
```

Comment: `np.array(derivs).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int))` Why'd you put NaN's in something you're turning into an `int *`? `np.zeros([ord, nx]).ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))` Why are you making a 2D array and then passing it as a `double *`?

Comment: The c code was originally for R, I was trying to implement it in python. If ```derivs``` was supposed to be an array of int and nans, and the other parameter was a 2D array, what type should I specify in c?

Comment: Does the C code work when you call it from R? Can you post the R code that uses it?

Comment: The R code is the bs() function in the splines package, which can be found at [link](https://github.com/cran/splines/blob/master/R/splineClasses.R). The first function splineDesign calls the c code.

Comment: They have [a check](https://github.com/cran/splines/blob/2395db94a78a8138e23e0a81a566b6ae5d0f3bce/R/splineClasses.R#L49-L52) that you're not doing, and it looks like the way you're calling it wouldn't pass that check. Also, their code uses neither 2D arrays nor NaNs.

Comment: When I tried to run their code, their code ```derivs <- as.integer(derivs)[ind]``` generates an array with one integer and others are NANs, and ```design = array(double(ord * nx), c(ord, nx))``` generates a 2D array...

Comment: Actually it's not NANs, but there is a 2D array.

Comment: You're right about the 2D array. But I think the check is the important part. Exactly what arguments were you passing to R's `splineDesign`?

Comment: I wasn't using the splineDesign function directly. I used the bs() function in the splines.R file, which calls the splineDesign function.

Comment: Okay, what arguments did you pass to `bs` then?

Comment: A minimal example would be ```bs(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))```

Comment: Why are you trying to port the messy spaghetti code from an ancient version of R instead of the nice clean code from modern R?

Comment: I'm trying to make a working code in python to build BSpline basis matrix. As far as I know, bs() in splines is still one of the most popular library to generate BSpline basis. Even a newer version splines2 uses the bs() as a base function. I'll try to find some way to work around. Thank you very much for you help!!

Comment: "As far as I know, bs() in splines is still one of the most popular library to generate BSpline basis." It still is, but https://svn.r-project.org/R/tags/R-4-0-0/src/library/splines/ is a much newer implementation of it than the one you linked to.

Comment: That looks good! Let me try if that one works... Thanks!